# IBM mfpdev CLI v8.0 issue in "mfpdev server add" in development environment

Tags: npm, ibm-mobilefirst

I tried below commands to add a server and run on console. Please help me to add and start the server successfully and open the console in the browser.

**Pratimas-Mac-mini:~ pratima$ mfpdev server add devconsole -u http://192.168.1.144:10081 -l admin -p admin -c myapp -s
Verifying server configuration...
Cannot connect to server 'devconsole' at 'http://192.168.1.144:10081'.
Missing runtime configuration details.: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.1.144:10081
Server profile 'devconsole' added successfully.**

**Pratimas-Mac-mini:~ pratima$ mfpdev server console devconsole
Opening console for server 'devconsole'**

It got opened in the browser

http://192.168.1.144:10081/mfpconsole/index.html#/dashboard&login=admin&password=admin

"This site can't be reached"

i read and followed the below link as well, still no luck.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/using-mobilefirst-cli-to-manage-mobilefirst-artifacts/#managing-mobilefirst-server-instances

Please let me know if i am missing something in the process

Comment: Verify your port and IP. In both CLI and browser it cannot be reached.

Comment: I verified, I extended my study and found I missed to install the developer kit. Now i installed the developer kit in my mac and able to open the console.                                                                                                          After that i installed in windows10 as well but i am not able to run the run.sh in my windows. i tried to run using cygwin but still it does not work. getting ./mfp-server/bin/server: line 783: java: command not found. Please help to run(run.sh) the server in windows

Comment: Use the run.cmd. Also, can you please mark your question as answered.

Comment: @VivinK Can you please tell me how to tun the android project and see the apk from the platforms folder in eclipse. i installed android studio, when i do "rightclick-> platforms/android/" -> Run As -> Android Studio Project nothing  happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be your server is not running on `Port 10081` which you can verify by running `http://192.168.1.144:10081/mfpconsole` in browser.

Usually MFP 8.0 Server's runs on `Port 9080` by default. Kindly verify on which port your MFP server is running before adding the server profile via MFPDev CLI.

Comment: I verified, I extended my study and found I missed to install the developer kit. Now i installed the developer kit in my mac and able to open the console. After that i installed in windows10 as well but i am not able to run the run.sh in my windows. i tried to run using cygwin but still it does not work. getting ./mfp-server/bin/server: line 783: java: command not found. Please help to run(run.sh) the server in windows

Comment: @SivaReddy It seems to be you don't have `java` installed in the machine. Please install Java in your machine before starting server. Refer [this documentation](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/development/mobilefirst/installation-guide/) for more details.

Comment: Yes i configured the JRE path in the Env.variables & then able to the run.cmd & stop.cmd. Thanks for your time vittal.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to tun the android project and see the apk from the platforms folder in eclipse. i installed android studio, when i do "rightclick-> platforms/android/" -> Run As -> Android Studio Project nothing happens.

Comment: @SivaReddy, where exactly did you try that? There is no rightclick platforms options within MFP.  Refer to :
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

Comment: I have create a cordova project in the eclipse with Thym and added android platform & mfp plugin to that.  i meant rightclick on the android platform in the created project